# When I create a table in SQL, how do I set an attribute not null?

Tags: sql, null

I wanna create a table in SQL, and if the I wanna set the attributes to NULL, how do I do it? 
For example, I wanna create a table named Courses and its attributes "CourseNo" and "Title" must not be null. I created one below:

```
CREATE TABLE Courses(
    CourseNo INTEGER CHECK(100<=CourseNo<=999) PRIMARY KEY,
    Title VARCHAR(100),
    )

ALTER TABLE Courses
ALTER COLUMN CourseNo INTEGER NOT NULL
ALTER COLUMN Title VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL
```

Is this correct?

Comment: Have you run it? Did you get any errors? If it executed without an error, did you try inserting `NULL` values? What happened? My point is - it would be faster and more of an learning experience for you to **try** it.

Comment: if you are declaring courseno as primary key it cannot be null

Answer (score 0, accepted):

whatever you wrote that one correct but good practice is to write `not null` at a time of defining table. 
do like this:

```
CREATE TABLE Courses(
    CourseNo INTEGER CHECK(100<=CourseNo<=999) PRIMARY KEY,
    Title VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    )
```

primary key is by default `NOT NULL` always, hence you no need to declare it as `NOT NULL`

`NOT NULL` in alter is used when u want to make change in column definations of table later

Answer (score 0):

Change that `Title VARCHAR(100)` to `Title VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL`.